# Center CALayer in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

How would I center a `CALayer` in a `UIView`?

I've got the following code but can't seem to get the `CALayer` centered in the view. The layer's image always seems to end up with its bottom right corner at the center of the screen.

**`UIView` code:**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    testLayer = [CALayer layer];
    testLayer = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    testLayer = kCAGravityCenter;

    testLayer.contents = (id) self.testImage.CGImage;

    [testLayer setPosition:self.center];

    [self.layer addSublayer:testLayer];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    testLayer.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the position in layoutSubviews.  You are doing it too early, I think the center isn't correct yet.